# Derivative not defined, but does exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the function f: $\ (x,y) = y \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $.

The derivative at the origin is zero. However, if I calculate the partial derivative with respect to x, for example, I get the following: $ \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $ Which isn't defined at the origin. What am I missing here?

Comment: The limit of $xy/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ does exist at zero.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation from which your formula for the derivative was obtained is based on assumption $x^2+y^2=0$: you differentiated square root, which is not differentiable at $0$. So, it is no surprise that the resulting formula is meaningless at $(0,0)$. This fact does not say anything about the existence of derivative at $(0,0)$; all we know is that the method you used to find the derivative does not apply to the point $(0,0)$.